# How to stop annoying big Notifications

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s7

I use a Samsung Galaxy 7. OS is Nougat.

Previously notifications used to be small texts in notifications area.

Now I get an annoying small popup window for every app upon notification.

Any ideas how to stop this?

Comment: If you are describing what I think you are, swiping either up, left, or right on the pop-up will clear it.

Comment: I have no issue clearing it. I just want to know if I can totally stop the popup behavior of the notifications.

Comment: I'm so fed of this behavior that I'm thinking to root my phone if that helps.

Comment: can someone with the same OS, or phone please let me know if the similar issue exists for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to *Heads-Up* notifications (those notifications which pop up on the top of your phone's screen).

The following methods have shown to **completely** disable them for all applications while **maintaining** regular notifications in the status bar. All of these methods are free. Some require a rooted device and some don't.

**Non rooted devices**

1. **ADB method**

   - Firstly install minimum [ADB/Fastboot setup](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118). You can find more instructions here: [New To Adb And Fastboot Guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2225405).
   - After enabling USB debugging, connect usb cable from device to computer.
   - Open command prompt (right click + shift) and enter the commands:

   `adb devices`

Check if your device is listed in output, then proceed

```
adb shell settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0
```

- reboot device and thats it!

**Rooted devices**

1. Using terminal

   - Install [Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en)  for Android.
   - Open the application. Use the following commands:

   `su`

   (The indicator should change from "$" to "#"). Next enter

   `settings put global heads_up_notifications_enabled 0`
2. **Using heads app switcher app**

   - One XDA developer has generously shared thier 50 lines of code embedded in this app to switch on/off Heads-Up notifications from quick settings for Android N
   - Root required. Reboot not required
   - Download [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=4063767&d=1488787386)

Acknowledgements:

- [Official Nougat - turn off Peek Notifications?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/help/official-nougat-off-peek-notifications-t3541332)

Comment: Sounds very promising. I will try when I get home.